# External script does not work with HTTPS connection

Tags: ssl, https

I embedded the following script on my HTTP website and it is working. But once I run my website with a SSL encryption the video does not playback.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ext.nicovideo.jp/thumb_watch/sm25096509?w=1035&amp;h=530"></script>
```

Why doesn't the script work on HTTPS? 
What do I have to do to get it working on HTTPS?

Answer (score 0):

Browsers prevent loading of *mixed content* whereby an HTTPs page loads an HTTP resource. The reason is that unencrypted script can access and exfiltrate data contained in the more secure embedding page.

Here are a couple of links for Firefox and Chrome:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Security/MixedContent
http://googleonlinesecurity.blogspot.co.uk/2011/06/trying-to-end-mixed-scripting.html

The only solution is to host the script on HTTPS.